Oracle Apex raised user-defined exception for start-workflow process page
I am constructing a business web by Oracle Apex. I found some problem when I set up processes for web page.
In web page, I designed 2 processes:

Interactive grid (edit mode) process for update/insert/delete mode. (Processing)
Start workflow for approval task. (After submit)
However, when I run web, it raises an user-defined error:

is_internal_error: false
ora_sqlcode: 1
ora_sqlerrm: ORA-06510: PL/SQL: unhandled user-defined exception ORA-06512: at "APEX_230200.WWV_FLOW_WORKFLOW", line 5148 ORA-06512: at "APEX_230200.WWV_FLOW_WORKFLOW", line 1109 ORA-06512: at "APEX_230200.WWV_FLOW_WORKFLOW", line 1005 ORA-06512: at "APEX_230200.WWV_FLOW_WORKFLOW", line 5086 ORA-06512: at "APEX_230200.WWV_FLOW_PROCESS_NATIVE", line 1116 ORA-06512: at "APEX_230200.WWV_FLOW_PROCESS_NATIVE", line 1478 ORA-06512: at "APEX_230200.WWV_FLOW_PLUGIN", line 3634
component.type: APEX_APPLICATION_PAGE_PROCESS
component.id: 7675264569296919
component.name: Start Workflow
error_backtrace:
ORA-06512: at "APEX_230200.WWV_FLOW_WORKFLOW", line 5148 ORA-06512: at "APEX_230200.WWV_FLOW_WORKFLOW", line 1109 ORA-06512: at "APEX_230200.WWV_FLOW_WORKFLOW", line 1005 ORA-06512: at "APEX_230200.WWV_FLOW_WORKFLOW", line 5086 ORA-06512: at "APEX_230200.WWV_FLOW_PROCESS_NATIVE", line 1116 ORA-06512: at "APEX_230200.WWV_FLOW_PROCESS_NATIVE", line 1478 ORA-06512: at "APEX_230200.WWV_FLOW_PLUGIN", line 3634 ORA-06512: at "APEX_230200.WWV_FLOW_PROCESS", line 192

This is my Update/Insert/Delete PLSQL code:
BEGIN
CASE 
WHEN :apex$row_status = 'C' THEN
INSERT INTO TMP_UPDATE (
EMP_ID, EMP_HANOI, EMP_HCM, EMP_DANANG, STATUS, OPERATION, NOTE, EDIT_BY, EDIT_ON
) VALUES (
:EMP_ID, :EMP_HANOI, :EMP_HCM, :EMP_DANANG, 'PENDING', 'INSERT', :NOTE, :APP_USER, SYSDATE
) RETURNING ROW_ID INTO :P8_ROW_ID;

WHEN :apex$row_status = 'U' THEN 
INSERT INTO TMP_UPDATE (
EMP_ID, EMP_HANOI, EMP_HCM, EMP_DANANG, STATUS, OPERATION, NOTE, EDIT_BY, EDIT_ON
) VALUES (
:EMP_ID, :EMP_HANOI, :EMP_HCM, :EMP_DANANG, 'PENDING', 'UPDATE', :NOTE, :APP_USER, SYSDATE
) RETURNING ROW_ID INTO :P8_ROW_ID;

WHEN :apex$row_status = 'D' THEN 
INSERT INTO TMP_UPDATE (
EMP_ID, EMP_HANOI, EMP_HCM, EMP_DANANG, STATUS, OPERATION, NOTE, EDIT_BY, EDIT_ON
) VALUES (
:EMP_ID, :EMP_HANOI, :EMP_HCM, :EMP_DANANG, 'PENDING', 'DELETE', :NOTE, :APP_USER, SYSDATE
) RETURNING ROW_ID INTO :P8_ROW_ID;
END CASE;
-- EXCEPTION
-- WHEN OTHERS THEN
-- -- Handle exceptions, log error messages or report errors
-- APEX_DEBUG_MESSAGE.LOG_MESSAGE(p_message => 'Error in workflow: ' || SQLERRM);
-- RAISE;
END;

and Workflow process retrieves P8_ROW_ID to be active but when starting workflow process, P8_ROW_ID is null.
Could you give me some solutions to tackle this issue?
